REST API - Limit Exception converting string to Blob
Based on my understanding, any inbound call to Custom REST service built in Salesforce gets heap size of 12 MB as it is considered asynchronous.
Currently, I have below code which when consumers call the endpoint, we send the data from salesforce
    @HttpPost
    global static SendAPIResponse handlePost() {
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(responseList));
        res.statusCode = 200;
        return null;
    }

In above code, responseList is the List<Object> that needs to be sent.
Since HttpPost doesnt support return type of List<Object> I am using RestResponse to build Blob after serializing the list.
So far it works perfectly but the problem is lets say when the List has too many records (>6MB) when i convert that to Blob, it throws error
System.LimitException: BlobValue length exceeds maximum: 6000000
Q1) If my understanding of 12MB asynchronous limit is correct, Will the 12MB limit doesnt come into picture when converting string to Blob. I tried this with a string of 6.1MB and still conversion to Blob throws me the system limit exception
Q2) With out using third party tools like Heroku/ middleware, is there any other approach with in Salesforce where I can use the full 12MB (or atleast 10MB) of the limit. My responses are usually between 6MB - 7MB. I understand there might be some other solutions like pagination etc but i wanted to check if anything else can be done here so i send the consumer full response which is usually 6 - 7MB

that clarified my first question that 12MB doesnt apply here and custom rest services are also subject to 6MB. Thankyou .

Yes, Based on my understanding, any inbound call to Custom REST service built in Salesforce gets heap size of 12 MB as it is considered asynchronous. statement is not correct.
